# Change the background color of desktop app icon in Windows 8 start screen

Tags: windows-8, icons, start-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a “metro” looking tile for a desktop application?](https://superuser.com/questions/493665/how-to-add-a-metro-looking-tile-for-a-desktop-application)
>   [How to customize tiles (bigger icon, different color) for desktop applications in the Start Screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/495659/how-to-customize-tiles-bigger-icon-different-color-for-desktop-applications-i)

On the Windows 8 start screen, there are the tiles for "metro" style apps and tiles containing the icons for desktop apps.

Each standard tile is about 120 x 120 pixels and for metro style apps, it's possible to work with the entire tile area and set your own background color.

However for desktop apps, the tile is composed of a centered 48 x 48 icon from the application and the title of the app.

Is there a way to either use a 120 x 120 icon or set a background color for the tile?

Comment: Do you mean just the color of the "Desktop" app/Live tile, or the color of the background for various non-Metro apps ("Desktop apps")?

Comment: Are you looking to customize these backgrounds and icons for your own apps you develop (so a global change for everyone for that app), or customizing each one per machine (so only change per app and only on your own machine)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a "metro" looking tile for a desktop application?](http://superuser.com/questions/493665/how-to-add-a-metro-looking-tile-for-a-desktop-application) Edit: [How to customize tiles (bigger icon, different color) for desktop applications in the Start Screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/495659/how-to-customize-tiles-bigger-icon-different-color-for-desktop-applications-i) might be an even more specific duplicate.

Comment: I'm looking to set a 120x120 icon for all users who install the desktop app on Windows 8. OblyTile is useful for customizing your own Start screen but I need something that works more generally. Looks like the only way is to create a metro app to launch the desktop app. Can't think why Microsoft have not allowed for this!

Answer (score -1):

The color of the Desktop "app" relies on the color of your background in the Desktop. For example if your background contains daisies then it will display daisies.

Comment: I think the op is referencing "Desktop apps" in general, not just the "Desktop" app/Live tile.