# Changing the Background Colour of a Single Tile?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize tiles (change/bigger icon, change color) for desktop applications in the Start Screen?](https://superuser.com/questions/495659/how-to-customize-tiles-change-bigger-icon-change-color-for-desktop-applicatio)

Is it possible to change the background colour of (desktop) application tiles when they are added to the Start Screen?

Apps from the store have different coloured backgrounds - which is fine, they are easy to distinguish - but when one uses a lot of desktop applications, it would be easier to find what I'm looking for (and looks more aesthetically pleasing) if I could change the background colour on a per-app basis.

I've been through the settings pane/context menus, and have searched on the web but I can't see a way to do it. Is there something I'm missing?

**Note**: I'd be ok with a third-party configuration setting if a native one doesn't exist, however I don't want to use the 'Classic Shell' start menu

**Note 2**: I'm not talking about the background of the Start Screen, I'm talking about the background colour of the tiles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize tiles (change/bigger icon, change color) for desktop applications in the Start Screen?](http://superuser.com/questions/495659/how-to-customize-tiles-change-bigger-icon-change-color-for-desktop-applicatio), [How To Create Tiles With Custom Colors On Start Screen](http://superuser.com/questions/492088/how-to-create-tiles-with-custom-colors-on-start-screen), [How to add a “metro” looking tile for a desktop application?](http://superuser.com/questions/493665/how-to-add-a-metro-looking-tile-for-a-desktop-application) and so on.

Comment: Thankyou @Karan, those didn't come up when I searched, nor as suggestions when I was writing the question. The closest I got was http://superuser.com/questions/416575/how-do-i-add-a-shortcut-to-a-website-to-the-windows-8-start-screen. It seems that OblyTile is the recommended solution in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [OblyTile](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1899865). It allows you to create new tiles of desktop apps and it allows you to configure the color:

[image]